# How do I find sql server instances in a given range of IP address es

Tags: sql-server

I want to discover SQL Server instance in a given range of IP address using C#. How do I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is source code for older versions of [SQLPing](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/Tools/FreeTools/tabid/65/Default.aspx)